# Help initializing EKF to a set position

Tags: ros, navigation, ekf, robot-localization, ekf-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had asked this question a while back, but [received no response](http://answers.ros.org/question/257101/unable-to-set_pose-if-odom0_differential-false/). Hopefully the revised subject line and info helps me come to a solution.

I'm running the latest robot_localization package on Kinetic/Ubuntu 16.

For testing certain functions of the vehicle, we would like to place the vehicle at a certain point in the map(which is already generated and published).
To initialize the EKF to a location, I use the /set_pose rosservice call, which works IF odom0_differential=true.
/set_pose does not work if odom0_differential=false. There is a tiny blip on the EKF output to the set location, but then the EKF starts at 0 again.

There are two sensors currently providing Pose data. The odometry(/odom) from wheel encoders and imu yaw(imu/data).

The EKF is setup as follows. Everything else is set to default.

```
map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

odom0: /odom
imu0:  /imu/data

odom0_config: [true,  true,  false,          
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]

imu0_config:  [false, false,  false,
               false, false,  true,
               false, false,  false,
               false, false,  true,
               false, false,  false]

odom0_differential: false
imu0_differential:  false

odom0_relative: true
imu0_relative:  true
```

Rossservice call, initializing EKF to (1,1):

```
rosservice call --wait /set_pose "pose:
  header:
    seq: 0
    stamp:
      secs: 0
      nsecs: 0
    frame_id: odom
  pose:
    pose:
      position: {x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0}
      orientation: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0}
    covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
      0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
      0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]"
```

Edit(April 4th, 2017, 8:15AM):
I've stripped my vehicle bag file to a new bag file called ekfTest.bag, with just odom+imu+tf data - [Download](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e44qgp9s7uerd0b/AACTLmmlyaAKuNB4oVcKYK3Ma?dl=0). This bag contains /tf, /odom and /imu/data topics.
Please note that I've turned off "publish_tf" in the EKF parameters as the bag file already has this /tf data.

I've also attached my ekf parameter file(ekf_template.yaml) and launch file.

1. Start the robot_localization node with the parameter file.
   2.Open a window to view EKF data: rostopic echo /odometry/filtered/pose/pose/position
   3.Run the bag file: rosbag play ekfTest.bag
2. Set pose:
   rosservice call /set_pose "pose: header: seq: 0 stamp: now frame_id: odom pose: pose: position: {x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0} orientation: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0} covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]"

Note: with @TomMoore's recommendation,  I've made w=1. I usually press tab after /set_pose and was not paying attention to orientation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258491/help-initializing-ekf-to-a-set-position/) by [bluehash](https://answers.ros.org/users/26693/bluehash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2017-04-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-04-04**:
Please post sample input messages from all sensors. Also, you are passing in an invalid quaternion (set `w` to 1.0).

**Comment by [bluehash](https://answers.ros.org/users/26693/bluehash/) on 2017-04-04**:
I've added data to the bottom of my pose.  I've made w=1. I usually press tab after /set_pose and was not paying attention to orientation. The default is 0.
This is a controlled test with sensor data(odom+imu) streaming into the EKF. I see the EKF latching to the /set_pose value and not change.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-05-03**:
Would you mind accepting the answer (circular checkbox)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah, sorry, didn't look at your config closely enough. You are fusing `X` and `Y` in your `odom0` config, which is pose data, so the first measurement you get after you call `set_pose` will snap it right back. In other words, this is happening:

- Time `t0`: filter gets measurement from `odom0`. `X` and `Y` position in the filter output will be very near the `odom0` measurement.
- Time `t1`: you call `set_pose` with some specific pose. EKF pose jumps to that position.
- Time `t2`: filter gets measurement from `odom0`. `X` and `Y` position in the filter output will be very near the `odom0` measurement.

This is why differential mode works: it converts the `odom0` pose to a velocity, which won't interfere with your `set_pose` call. All `set_pose` is doing is sending your robot to the location you send it. If you then give it measurements that tell it that it is somewhere else, it's going to jump back.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bluehash](https://answers.ros.org/users/26693/bluehash/) on 2017-05-02**:
Thanks Tom!